# How do I set the filename for a file download in Google AppEngine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, http, http-headers

How do I set the filename for a file download with Google AppEngine? I tried setting `Content-Disposition` but AppEngine strips that header out in production (works in development).

#### Code

```
    resp.setContentType( "application/octet-stream" );
    resp.setHeader( "Content-Disposition:", "attachment; filename=" + "\"" + fileName + "\"" );
```

#### Development Headers

```
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="logs-2013-11-06-15-23-21.csv"
```

#### Production Headers

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
X-AppEngine-Estimated-CPM-US-Dollars: $0.001434
X-AppEngine-Resource-Usage: ms=220 cpu_ms=224
Date: Wed, 06 Nov 2013 20:25:00 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate
Server: Google Frontend
Content-Length: 12713
Alternate-Protocol: 80:quic
```

#### Reference

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/#Java_Responses
https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10247

Answer (score 3):

Late to the party...

Just is case it helps, the first argument to setHeader should be "Content-Disposition" (Trailing : should *not* be present).

The chrome browser's save dialog then recognizes the filename value provided. (In my application the content type is being set to "application/octet-stream"). This is what worked for me:

```
response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename='" + filename + "'");
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the file you want to download is a csv file try

```
resp.setContentType( "text/plain" );
resp.setHeader( "Content-Disposition:", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
```

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work. It merely displays the text in the browser, and since this is a GWT app, it loses all state. It still strips off the Content-Disposition header. Would like to force a download.

Answer (score 0):

Try "text/csv" or "application/csv" instead of "text/plain", both have worked.